# LayoutItems and Alignment

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am a bit confused with Lightning Layout and LayoutItems... I want to create a custom lighhtning component which is almost the same as default Task compact Layout... I have done this until now...

```
<!-- 22/11/2019 @ggalaios Tasks Management Lightning Component -->

<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowScreens,lightning:actionOverride"
                controller="ea_HandleTaskAssignments"
                access="global">
    <!--Attribute that indicates whether task is open or not in order to show appropriate button-->
    <aura:attribute name="openTask" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="infoText" type="String"/>
    <!--Loading spinner Attribute -->
    <aura:attribute name="spinner" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="taskRecord" type="Task"/>

    <!-- 05/09/2019 George Galaios: call doInit Controller function on page refresh --> 
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<lightning:layout class="slds-page-header slds-page-header--object-home">
            <lightning:layoutItem >
                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:task" alternativeText="Εργασία"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
                <div class="page-section page-header">
                    <h1 class="slds-text-heading--label">ΕΡΓΑΣΙΑ</h1>
                    <div class="slds-text-title_bold slds-text-heading_large">
                        {!v.taskRecord.Subject}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>

            <!-- Buttons -->
            <div class="slds-float_right">
                <lightning:button label="Επεξεργασία" variant="neutral" onclick="{!c.editRecord}" iconName="utility:edit_form" iconPosition="right" />
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.openTask}">
                    <lightning:button label="Ανάληψη Εργασίας" variant="neutral" onclick="{!c.takeTaskResponsibility}" iconName="utility:privately_shared" iconPosition="right" disabled="{!v.disabled}"/>
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <lightning:button label="Αναίρεση Ανάληψης Εργασίας" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.leaveTaskResponsibility}" iconName="utility:change_owner" iconPosition="right" disabled="{!v.disabled}"/>
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
            </div>
            <!--End of Buttons -->
        </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

In the picture it is shown how my component is displayed. I only want the 2 buttons to go on the right but i cannot find a way! I tried to use LayoutItem size="2" class="right-align" but it affects the way other stuff are displayed. Any ideas?

[image]